# Trying to connect to a network printer/scanner

Tags: printer, scanner

I'm trying to connect to a network printer/scanner and I'm completely lost.

I found its IP with `fing` (its output `192.168.1.200`/Ricoh). Disconnecting the network cable makes it disappear from the output. When I `ping` it, it pings back.

I tried to install it through CUPS `http://localhost:631/admin`. `Find new printers` shows none. `Add Printer` shows me a list of possible protocols (ipp14, ipps, ipp, HPLIP). Nothing that I set here seems to work.

I'm also pretty interested in the scanner. I scanned some pages, and they are saved in the printer's internal HDD. Given the IP above, what's the easiest way of getting them?

If this helps, it's a Ricoh Aficio MP C2500.

Comment: You did run apt-get build-dep cups; apt install cups, and you downloaded hplip from the original hp website and followed the instructions to install the ppd for your specific printer, you need the ppd file or you'll never find your printer, if you did all that, run the setup and manually enter the printers ip address which is what I had to do

Comment: What remote protocols (e.g. IPP, LPD, SMB for printing, FTP, SMB for storage) [are enabled on the printer](http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi/0001034/0001034259/VB2298558/B2298558.pdf)? Are you allowed to make changes to the MFP?

Comment: Multi functional printer (MFP)<>(MFD) meaning scanner, fax, printer. it depends on your printers model ?

Comment: @ErikF: yes, I'm allowed to make changes about anything. I'll check what's enabled. Having FTP would be fantastic.